# Formatting kubectl output

Tags: docker, formatting, kubernetes

I'm trying to format the output of this command:

```
kubectl get pods test
```

like docker I'm trying to format the outout just for it to print me the name and the status of all pods.
docker:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Status}},{{.Name}}"
```

Any way I can do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with [custom columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns):

```
kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns=STATUS:.status.phase,STARTED:.status.startTime,NAME:.metadata.name
```